# How to refresh the interface across threads in VTK

Tags: vtk, vtk-9.1.0

I want to use VTK to implement such a function:
1.An independent thread loops to read a video
2.After reading a frame of video data, the main interface displays, and the thread will not block the main interface
How can I do that? May I use callback func to do that?
English is not my native language, please forgive.

I tried using vtkcommand to add listening events. When the data in vtkImageImport changes, I called a callback function to update vtkImageViewer2, but it failed